# RewriteRule for special case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a requirement for proxying  a request at apache in case requeset is coming for /anotherserver and has query parameter like name.

So incoming URL would be...

mywebsite.com is running on apache.
 http://mywebsite.com/anotherserver/admin/mypage.aspx?name=<>

It should be proxied to which it is running a portal at IIS server.
http://<>-mywebsite.com/admin/mypage.aspx

I am writing my rules as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/anotherserver.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^anotherserver/(.*)$  http://%1-mywebsite.com/$1 [NC,P,L]
```

This rule is not running, fine. Is anything wrong with this rule? How can I make it work. I want this as Proxy rule only.

Comment: Corrected first condition, still doesn't work

Comment: My actual problem boils down to :   can i use apache proxy such that http://mywebsite.com/mydir/fullpath  will get proxied to http://anotherserver.com/fullpath. http://mywebsite.com/mydir/someotherstyff  is displayed on my browser. Keeping mydir in base path is mandatory for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant (and contradicting) `RewriteCond`. Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^anotherserver(/.*)?$  http://%1-mywebsite.com/$1 [NC,P,L]
```

Problem is this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/anotherserver.* [NC]
```

Which means execute rule if URI is NOT starting with `/anotherserver` and your pattern is matching `^anotherserver`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.    I corrected my first condition. I don;t want this rule to run always but only in case it is coming for another server and with query parameter. It still doesn't work. :(                                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/anotherserver.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^anotherserver/(.*)$  http://%1-mywebsite.com/$1 [NC,P,L]

Comment: Even after correction `RewriteCond` is redundant since `RewriteRule ^anotherserver(/.*)?$ ` is applying same pattern against `REQUEST_URI`. Are you sure mod_proxy is working correctly? Try replacing `P` by `R` for testing and see if you get redirect in browser.